# Flume won't load Twitter data to HDFS

Tags: api, hadoop, twitter, terminal, flume

I am trying to load Twitter data into Hadoop. It says that it has processed nearly 25000 files, but when I check Hadoop I always find the folder empty.
This is the command I am using

> flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -f flume.conf

Here is a small caption

> 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 25,000 docs
> 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Total docs indexed:
> 25,000, total skipped docs: 0 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO
> twitter.TwitterSource:     45 docs/second 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO
> twitter.TwitterSource: Run took 545 seconds and processed: 21/07/18
> 19:40:03 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     0.012 MB/sec sent to index
> 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     6.708 MB text sent
> to index 21/07/18 19:40:03 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: There were 0
> exceptions ignored:  21/07/18 19:40:05 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:
> Processed 25,100 docs 21/07/18 19:40:06 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter:
> Creating /home/hadoopusr/flumetweets/FlumeData.1626629459197.tmp
> 21/07/18 19:40:06 WARN hdfs.HDFSEventSink: HDFS IO error
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException: /home (is not a
> directory)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkIsDirectory(FSPermissionChecker.java:538)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:278)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:206)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:507)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1612)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkTraverse(FSDirectory.java:1630)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.resolvePath(FSDirectory.java:551)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.resolvePathForStartFile(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:291)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2282)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2225)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:728)

**This is my Flume.config file**

#Naming the components on the current agent.

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter

TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

#Describing/Configuring the source

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels=MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = ************

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret =************

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = ************

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = ************

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords =covid,covid-19,coronavirus

#Describing/Configuring the sink
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = /home/hadoopusr/flumetweets

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 600

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100

#Describing/Configuring the channel

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 1000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000

#Binding the source and sink to the channel

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel

Comment: I’m not really familiar with Flume, but this seems like a meaningful error: `HDFS IO error org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException: /home (is not a directory)`

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing that out. All fixed... Can you check you this error please? Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=amel, access=WRITE, inode="/":hadoopusr:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x

Comment: I guess it suggests your user does not have write permission to HDFS, but I’m not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you fixed your first error, now you get a permission error upon writing to the HDFS root path as the `user=amel`

In your config you have

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = /home/hadoopusr/flumetweets
```

But, I'm guessing either `/home` or `/home/hadoopusr` does not exist, so that directory is trying to get created.

However, your user is not `hadoopusr` (your HDFS superuser), so there is not permissions to do so

Your options therefore are either

1. run `flume-ng agent` as the `hadoopusr` (`sudo su hadoopusr -c flume-ng agent ...`)
2. Change the HDFS path in the config to use `/home/amel` (after you create that path and give yourself permissions on it) `sudo su hadoopusr; hadoop fs -mkdir /home/amel; hadoop fs chown -R amel /home/amel; hadoop fs -chmod -R 760 /home/amel`

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your Flume.config file:
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs